# Can a client certificate be revoked and reissued with the same name in OpenVpn?

Tags: openvpn, certificate

> Can a client certificate be revoked and reissued with the same name in OpenVpn?
>
> Please Help.

Comment: What kind of research have you already done? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSL terms, there should be no problems with this. The serial number and hash of the certificate may be the same. Its all part of the standard lifecycle of a certificate. The fact that it is a client certificate makes no matter.

Disclaimer: I have no experience with OpenVPN.